# Terraform conditions in a module

Tags: module, terraform, azure-application-gateway

I am trying to create some simple logic when calling applicationg gateway module.

When creating WAF v2 application gateway I want to specify more attributes that simple application gateway can't handle and they won't be described.

```
resource "azurerm_application_gateway" {
  name                = var.appgatewayname
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location

......................

  waf_configuration {
    enabled                  = "${length(var.waf_configuration) > 0 ? lookup(var.waf_configuration, "enabled", "") : null }"
    firewall_mode            = "${length(var.waf_configuration) > 0 ? lookup(var.waf_configuration, "firewall_mode", "") : null }"
............
```

Calling module:

```
module "GWdemo" {
  source      = "./...."

  sku-name     = "WAF_v2"
  sku-tier     = "WAF_v2"
  sku-capacity = 1
  waf-configuration = [
    {
      enabled                  = true
      firewall_mode            = "Detection"
}
```

Am I thinking right that if waf-configuration map is specified it should specify following settings is applied and if not than null?

Comment: Does it work? If not do you get a specific error?

Comment: Error: Invalid function argument

  on module/main.tf line 28, in resource "azurerm_application_gateway" :
  28:     enabled                  = "${length(var.waf_configuration) > 0 ? lookup(var.waf_configuration, "enabled", "") : null }"
    |----------------
    | var.waf_configuration is tuple with 1 element

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.

Comment: Error: "waf_configuration.0.enabled": required field is not set

  on module/main.tf line 17, in resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "agw":
  17: resource "azurerm_application_gateway"  {

Comment: Please edit the error into your answer and appropriately format it so people can read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with Terraform we often want to reframe problems involving a conditional test into problems involving a collection that may or may not contain elements, because the Terraform language features are oriented around transforming collections into configuration on an element-by-element basis.

In your case, you have a variable that is already a list, so it could work to just ensure that its default value is an empty list rather than `null`, and thus that you can just generate one `waf_configuration` block per element:

```
variable "waf_configuration" {
  type = list(object({
    enabled       = bool
    firewall_mode = string
  }))
  default = []
}
```

Then you can use a [`dynamic` block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks) to generate one `waf_configuration` block per element of that list:

```
  dynamic "waf_configuration" {
    for_each = var.waf_configuration
    content {
      enabled       = waf_configuration.value.enabled
      firewall_mode = waf_configuration.value.firewall_mode
    }
  }
```

---

Although it doesn't seem to apply to this particular example, another common pattern is a variable that can be set to enable something or left unset to disable it. For example, if your module was designed to take only a *single* optional WAF configuration, you might define the variable like this:

```
variable "waf_configuration" {
  type = object({
    enabled       = bool
    firewall_mode = string
  })
  default = null
}
```

As noted above, the best way to work with something like that in Terraform is to recast it as a list that might be empty. Because it's a common situation, there is a shorthand for it via [splat expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#splat-expressions):

```
  dynamic "waf_configuration" {
    for_each = var.waf_configuration[*]
    content {
      enabled       = waf_configuration.value.enabled
      firewall_mode = waf_configuration.value.firewall_mode
    }
  }
```

When we apply the `[*]` operator to a value of a non-list/non-set type, Terraform will test to see if the value is `null`. If it *is* null then the result will be an empty list, while if it is *not* null then the result will be a single-element list containing that one value.

After converting to a list we can then use it in the `for_each` argument to `dynamic` in the usual way, accessing the attributes from that possible single element inside the `content` block. We don't need to repeat the conditionals for each argument because the `content` block contents are evaluated only when the list is non-empty.

Comment: [*] operator was something new for me :) Thanks for very clear explanation

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to upgrade to Terraform v0.12.x and this should get a much easier to do. I would leverage the new dynamic block syntax to make the block optional based on whatever condition you need to use.

Here is a rough example, but should get you going in the correct direction.

```
dynamic "waf-configuration " {
  for_each = length(var.waf_configuration) > 0 ? [] : [1]
  content {
    enabled       = "${length(var.waf_configuration) > 0 ? lookup(var.waf_configuration, "enabled", "") : null }"
    firewall_mode = "${length(var.waf_configuration) > 0 ? lookup(var.waf_configuration, "firewall_mode", "") : null }"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it looks like a right condition. Nevertheless if I pass waf_configuration as null and try to create  app gateway without waf I get This value is null, so it does not have any attributes. :/ Probably I need to go the way of creating 2 seperate modules. One with waf functionality and one regular app gateway